# variables in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf to send variables from the controller to the view (HTML file) but it says that is null.

This is my `HelloController` (`src/main/java/controller/HelloController`):

```java
@Controller
    public class HelloController {
        public String mensaje = "Springboot";
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String index(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

This is the HTML file (`src/main/resouces/templates/index.html`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="'Hello' + ${mensaje} + '!'"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The message in the browser should be "Hello Springboot!" but it says "Hellonull!"

Any help?

Comment: your example works fine. well almost. it writes "HelloSpringboot!" without a space. Did you re-compile, or restart? Auto-reloading requires the "pring-boot-devtools" dependency as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below and let me know.

```
  @Controller
public class HelloController {

    private String mensaje;

    public HelloController() {
        this.mensaje = "Springboot";
    }


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

in the above i tried by adding constructor to the HelloController class , that will make sure that variable `mensaje` is initialized correctly.

Comment: Wow! No idea why i was getting null all the time, thanks for your time. It works fine now :)